# Create an Array for each date and populate each array according to matching dates

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, while-loop

currently I am creating a travel application.

I have connected API's together with google maps, where the user can "Add a place / hotel to their itinerary which is then stored on a database.

I want to be able to create an array with every place/hotel/flight on a specific date so that I can output a calendar for the user to show them what they are doing each day.

So far I have;

```
$eachDay = array(); $i = 0; $j = 0;

foreach ($array as $entriesRow) {
$i++;
$eachDay[$i]['date'] = $entriesRow;
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

        if ($eachDay[$i]['date'] == $row2['dateGoing']) {
            $j++;
            $eachDay[$i]['title'][$j] = $row2['title'];
        }
    }
}
```

and the return I get is

```
Array ( [date] => 2017-03-21 [title] => Array ( [1] => Sydney Harbour Bridge [2] => World Tower ) ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-22 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-23 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-24 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-25 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-26 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-27 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-28 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-29 ) Array ( [date] => 2017-03-30 )
```

This is fine for the first day but it doesn't seem to loop through the other days like the 2017-03-22, it just displays the date. I have data for each of the other days.

I'm defiently missing something, like another loop or something else, but i'm just not sure!

Thank you in advance, sorry if it is not explained very well.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
foreach ($array as $entriesRow) {
$i++;
$eachDay[$i]['date'] = $entriesRow;
$j = 0;
foreach ($places as $v) {
    if($eachDay[$i]['date'] == $v['dateGoing']){
        $eachDay[$i]['title'][$j] = $v['title'];
        $j++;
    }
}
```